# Query To Clean Old Table Or Create New Table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `players` table with certain player information and a `jumps` table with stats about a particular "jump" any player may have performed in a game that was logged to the database. The `jumps` table also includes the corresponding "player id" which is also available in the `players` table.

Table structure is as follows (only showing the important columns):

`players`:

```
id | name | ip | authid | lastseen
```

`jumps`:

```
pid | type | distance | wpn
```

"Jumps" are logged by `type`, `distance`, and `wpn`. A row is updated whenever a larger `distance` is achieved *per* `type` *and* `wpn`, meaning there are different entries per `type` and different entries per `wpn` for each `pid`.

## Problem

---

The plugin used to save the information used to be set by `ip` rather than `authid`, which has resulted in excess entries in both tables where a different `ip` corresponds to an additional `id`/`pid`.

## Goal

---

1. Starting with the `players` table, I would like to find and remove all rows for each `authid` that do not contain the largest `lastseen` value for that particular `authid`. In the end there should be only one row per `authid`.
2. *Now the hard part*: I cannot simply perform a delete query first to accomplish **1**. I would probably need to perform that task last, because I need to know the `id`/`pid` in order to update all rows in the `jumps` table with the unique `id` retained from **1**. However, wait! There's more! Remember how entries used to be created by `ip` rather than `authid`? That has now potentially created "overlapping" rows because there could be multiple `id`/`pid` values per `authid`. These now need to be deleted.

Confused yet? Let me provide an example below:

## Example

---

Here I've performed a simple join to match corresponding rows in both tables and provide an example:

`SELECT * FROM uq_jumps INNER JOIN uq_players ON uq_jumps.pid = uq_players.id WHERE authid="STEAM_X:X:XXX" AND type="bj"`

This results in the following which I've reordered/formatted slightly better for readability:

```
675 | bj | 205251568 | awp
675 | name1 | 0.0.0.0 | STEAM_X:X:XXX | 1395562981

2457 | bj | 244130768 | knife
2457 | name2 | 11.11.11.11 | STEAM_X:X:XXX | 1384822930

2566 | bj | 246756784 | usp
2566 | name3 | 10.10.10.10| STEAM_X:X:XXX | 1381841664

2693 | bj | 242543040 | knife
2693 | name3 | 9.9.9.9 | STEAM_X:X:XXX | 1381934217

3483 | bj | 235620544 | usp
3483 | name3 | 8.8.8.8 | STEAM_X:X:XXX | 1382803345

3701 | bj | 243075456 | usp
3701 | name2 | 7.7.7.7 | STEAM_X:X:XXX | 1384996069

3764 | bj | 244422656 | usp
3764 | name3 | 6.6.6.6 | STEAM_X:X:XXX | 1383253511

4070 | bj | 243392880 | knife
4070 | name3 | 5.5.5.5 | STEAM_X:X:XXX | 1383550208

4179 | bj | 240038976 | knife
4179 | name2 | 4.4.4.4 | STEAM_X:X:XXX | 1383642095

4260 | bj | 243244656 | usp
4260 | name2 | 3.3.3.3 | STEAM_X:X:XXX | 1383821359

5369 | bj | 242361200 | knife
5369 | name2 | 2.2.2.2 | STEAM_X:X:XXX | 1384629584

5905 | bj | 245641984 | usp
5905 | name2 | 1.1.1.1 | STEAM_X:X:XXX | 1385424952

675 | bj | 245942608 | usp
675 | name1 | 0.0.0.0 | STEAM_X:X:XXX | 1395562981

675 | bj | 212841424 | m249
675 | name1 | 0.0.0.0 | STEAM_X:X:XXX | 1395562981
```

The plugin that updates and inserts rows considers "knife" to be equivalent to "usp" so in the end the only entries of the above that should be kept are:

```
675 | bj | 205251568 | awp
675 | name1 | 0.0.0.0 | STEAM_X:X:XXX | 1395562981

2566 | bj | 246756784 | usp
2566 | name3 | 10.10.10.10| STEAM_X:X:XXX | 1381841664

675 | bj | 212841424 | m249
675 | name1 | 0.0.0.0 | STEAM_X:X:XXX | 1395562981
```

---

I'm quite at a loss here as to how to generate a new table of unique entries or select/delete entries that should correctly be deleted or kept. My initial thoughts were to begin by using something like the join statement I posted above.

Now I could easily do this via multiple queries and iterating over result arrays, etc. in a PHP script but I was told by someone that **2** could be done in a single query (of course this person has yet to prove their point).

Any advice, thoughts, or even a starting point would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First copy players table structure into a temporary table, let us say new_players

```
CREATE TABLE new_players SELECT * FROM players WHERE 1=2;
```

Now insert desired authid and lastseen fields in newly created table

```
INSERT INTO new_players 
SELECT authid, MAX(lastseen) AS lastseen FROM players GROUP BY authid;
```

Fill up the remaining fields

```
UPDATE new_players np JOIN players p 
  ON np.authid=p.authid AND np.lastseen=p.lastseen 
SET np.id   = p.id,
    np.name = p.name,
    np.ip   = p.ip
;
```

Remap pid in jumps with correct one (as per selected records in new_players)

```
UPDATE jumps j LEFT JOIN new_players np ON j.pid = np.id SET
j.pid = (SELECT np2.id FROM players p JOIN new_players np2 
           ON p.authid=np2.authid AND p.lastseen=np2.lastseen 
         WHERE p.id=j.pid LIMIT 1
        )
WHERE np.id IS NULL;
```

Now you are safe to clean unwanted records

```
DELETE p.* FROM players p LEFT JOIN new_players np ON p.id=np.id 
WHERE np.id IS NULL;
```

Finaly clear the jumps table

```
DELETE j.* FROM jumps LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT pid, type, wpn, MAX(distance) AS distance FROM jumps GROUP BY pid, type, wpn
) j2 ON j.pid=j2.pid AND j.type=j2.type AND j.wpn=j2.wpn AND j.distance=j2.distance
WHERE j2.pid IS NULL;
```

**NOTE:** as I can't test the code so not sure about the syntax validity. but I hope you will get the main idea.
**NOTE:** always backup befor testing something new